# regEx expression for detecting javascript call function

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

For example, there is `@"javascript:viewData(3713, 'A', 89360)"` string.

I want to extract 3713, A and 89360 from the string.

For Java, "`viewData\(([^\(]*),[\s\S]\'([^\(]*)\',[\s\S]([^\(]*)\)`" can extract those strings successfully.

However, I couldn't successfully extract them in iOS Objective-C.

My code is below:

```
NSString *searchedString = @"javascript:viewData(3713, 'A', 89360)";
NSRange   searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length]);
NSString *pattern = @"<HERE THE PATTERN NEEDED>";
NSError  *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:searchedString options:0 range:searchedRange];
```

Then the matched string could be as:

`[searchedString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]` .. and so on.

How can I set the Pattern?

Comment: Update your question with the pattern you actually tried in Objective-C. And show the results you obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the regex pattern is supposed to work in Objective-C, too.

However you have to escape all backslashes:

```
NSString *pattern = @"viewData\\(([^\\(]*),[\\s\\S]\\'([^\\(]*)\\',[\\s\\S]([^\\(]*)\\)";
```

Comment: You need to do the same in Java as well so that's not likely the issue (which is why I asked the OP to update their question).

Comment: @rmaddy It seems to have been the issue ;-)

Comment: Since the OP refuses to update their question, we'll just have to assume so.